# print name , type and size of files or directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to print the Name,Type and size of files or directories under my current directory. I would like the output to be like the following :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKduT.png)

I have tried using the `file *` command and i get the first two columns and i miss the size column . I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `stat` to get the last piece of information.

Comment: how could i combine stat with file in order to get and the size column ?

Comment: `stat filename` or `stat *.txt`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use stat for this. With stat you can specify the output format you want. do `man stat` for more information

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


printf "Name\t\tType\t\tSize\n"

for file_folder in *;do
    stat --printf="%n\t%F\t%skb\n" "${file_folder}"
done
```